# Weird Hyperlink behavior in OneNote for local links

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-onenote, note-taking

I'm a big fan of OneNote and use it very often for my daily note-taking activities. Right now, I am facing a really weird behavior of hyperlink function in OneNote for local hyperlinks. I mean all hyperlinks that are pointing to to my local hard drive files and folders. However, the hyperlink function working perfectly while using for website links, internal OneNote notebook or section links.

Can anyone tell me what can be the possible causing of disabled hyperlink behavior locally?

Comment: Anybody can help me?

Comment: Would love to help, but your question needs more detail.
Can you provide an example of a link that *does* work, and a like that doesnt?  Be sure to include the actual properties of the link (what you see when you hover your mouse over it).  Another helpful bit of info would be `what version of OneNote are you using`?

Comment: I'm using OneNote 2013, the all local hyperlinks pointing to hard drive files or folder don't open whenever I click them. An icon blinks in the taskbar but immediately hide. Nothing happens

Comment: When I tried to use OneNote on my Virtual OS, it seems working fine. It looks some issues with in my Windows 7 OS that causing such weird hyperlink behavior

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just want to inform all of you that my problem has been resolved after installing 'System Mechanic Pro'. It's a complete system utilities and maintenance tool. After running all the tuning my this problem has gone now. So, if anyone has similar problem. I hope you will able to solve this after installing this program. You can download this below

http://www.iolo.com/downloads/download-system-mechanic/

Comment: Is this spam??? I think so..

Comment: Not a spam. I had a virus problem which caused issues that solved by using above. it looks like not the point but it eventually solved my problem